# Not getting all the apps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I open all apps I am only getting Outlook, Calendar, People and Tasks. I know those apps are only got I3 license but I got I3.

I've tried to restart my computer, clear the cache and cleared the log. Tried different browsers, and checked the admin center to see what Licenses I got.

Anyone know what the problem may be?

[image]